# Loading water layer from webpage maps-for-free.com into QGIS?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, basemap, loading, quickmapservices

I have loaded the relief map from https://maps-for-free.com/ using plugin QuickMapServices. The process is as follows: in my data_sources folder (C:\Users\PC1.qgis2\python\plugins\quick_map_services\data_sources), I created a new folder called freemap_relief and inside that folder I saved a notepad file named metadata.ini, and then typed in this notepad file these following lines:

> [general]
>   id = freemap_relief
>   type = TMS
>   is_contrib = True
>
> [ui]
>   group = Freemap
>   alias = FreemapRelief
>   icon = freemap.svg
>
> [license]
>   name = CC0
>   link = http://creativecommons.org/
>   copyright_text = unknown state
>   copyright_link = http://www.maps-for-free.com
>   terms_of_use = http://www.maps-for-free.com
>
> [tms]
>   url = http://maps-for-free.com/layer/relief/z{z}/row{y}/{z}_{x}-{y}.jpg
>   zmax = 19

Then I restarted my QGIS, and clicked on Web > QuickMapservices > Freemap > Freemaprelief:
[image]

And then the map was successfully loaded:

[image]

However, the relief map at https://maps-for-free.com/ has water layer and some other layers like street, admin, crop, sand, etc. but the map loaded to QGIS has no layer at all.

I just want to add only the water layer, but how do I do that?

My QGIS version is 2.18.21 running on Win10 x64 bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maps-for-free.com only provides tiles of shaded relief data from GTOPO30 and SRTM. if you click on the `i` icon located on the upper left side of the map in the link you provided [https://maps-for-free.com/](https://maps-for-free.com/#close), you will notive that the water data are coming from different source which is `World Vmap0`. You can use QMS search to search for `World Vmap0` and add the tiles to the canvas:

[image]

Right-click on the `World Vmap0` layer -> go to Style -> use blending mode of `Soft light` to see the water map overlaying the shaded relief map and having the effect above:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. It really works. To make the water layer display, the layer ''freemaprelief'' also needs to be changed as follows: Rgiht click on ''freemaprelief'' layer > properties > style > color rendering: in Blending mode, select ''Multiply''. This is the screenshot of the map in my QGIS: https://kek.gg/i/4znHzC.png

Comment: If I want to add other layers such as: crop, grass, forest, sand, street, etc., what keywords will I have to type in QMS search to add them ?

Comment: Moreover, after exporting as image (PNG) of the print composer of the map, the river does not appear in the exported PNG image if the map resolution exceeds 1200x848 pixels. https://kek.gg/i/74xmj8.png (map as in print composer),  https://kek.gg/i/k72nM.png (map after exporting without water layer, its resolution is 1500x1060), https://kek.gg/i/5zSW9x.png (selecting resolution for exporting map composer).

Comment: @Zhetdudf the river does not appear when you export from print composer because it has different CSR from freemaprelief. The river map uses `EPSG: 4326 in WGS84`, while freemaprelief uses `EPSG: 3857 in WGS84/Pseudo Mercator`. There is no way to convert the CRS of WMS data at user level, it should comverted from the source. I suggest to use ESRI World Topo. It has everything you want in one map including shaded relief, river, and other detailed information. Type ESRI World Topo in QMS and you will find it.

Comment: Thanks very much for your information,  ahmadhanb. It works.